# Different Maximum server memory across Availability Replicas

Tags: sql-server-2014, availability-groups, configuration, memory

I have a scenario in SQL Server 2014 AlwaysOn High Availability where other services are running in one of the Secondary read-only replicas.

These services obviously demand additional memory. Is there any good practice or specific reason why SQL Server should have the same memory configuration across different replicas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any good practice or specific reason why SQL Server should have the same memory configuration across different replicas?

This is definitely not a rule or prerequisite, normally people tend to keep configuration same so that when failover happens and secondary becomes primary should should not face resource crunch and performance should not get affected. If you know that secondary, which can become primary for short duration, could survive with low RAM and performance is acceptable go ahead and add less RAM. But normally you should keep things same so as to avoid any surprise.

Answer (score 1):

That’s due to fact it (SECONDARY) has to serve same level of work load as PRIMARY. I.e. when PRIMARY is memory intensive for 32GB, and SECONDARY limits to 24GB in the incident when it’s become PRIMARY it could perform same as primary the impact (8GB Memory) could be in various factors

- Additional connections might not established
- Existing requests might be slower
- Log redo could be backlogged 
  Etc..